# Using replace with std::ranges::views

Tags: c++, c++20, msvc12

I am trying to learn ranges in C++20 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

I created a function to make lowercase in a string and replace all spaces by '_'.

```cpp
template <typename R>
auto cpp20_string_to_lowercase_without_spaces( R&& rng )
{
    auto view = rng
        | std::ranges::views::transform( ::tolower )
        | std::ranges::views::common;

    std::ranges::replace( view, ' ', '_' );
    return view;
}
```

And I got the following errors:

```
Error   C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found  
Error   C7602   'std::ranges::_Replace_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

I tried to use `view.begin(), view.end()` I tried to use the `std::ranges::copy` before call std::ranges::replace.

Is it something I am doing wrong?

PS: In the project settings, I had to select `Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)` because with `ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)` with the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 preview I can't use views without compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform` creates a non-modifiable view. Specifically, it creates a range containing objects that are manufactured as needed. They have no permanent, fixed storage, so they cannot be "replaced" with something else.

You can copy the range into a container and then execute your replace operation on the container.

Comment: I tried to use the auto range = std::ranges::copy(view); but that line gives me a few errors saying that I cannot use range without initializing. of course in replace I use range instead of view in this case.

Comment: @Check: `ranges::copy` copies from a range to another range. It doesn't create a container; you have to do that. Please look at the documentation for the functions you're using *before* using them.